# How to change size of image based on screen size?

Tags: html, css

I want a banner to be displayed over 50% of the width of a large screen (desktop) and 100% of the width on a small screen (iphone).

At the moment the image is displayed over 50% of the screen for every device:

```
.advert-img {
    width: 50%;
    height:auto
}
```

How can I vary the width based on screen size?

Is this possible with all browsers? i.e. old blackberry browser

Comment: With phones now having high pixel counts you should be careful using the media tags. You may want to try using js to detect mobile user agent like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser

Answer (score 4):

You need [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to accomplish this. In your case, the css would look like this:

```
.advert-img {
  width: 50%
  height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .advert-img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

You can replace `480px` with whatever works best for your content in terms of a mobile breakpoint

Comment: Related media query: Orientation. 
Depending on what you're building, a combination of max-width/max-height and orientation can help effectively display information on desktop, mobile, and tablets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Media Queries to differentiate the width of the device.. Let's say you want to differentiate a mobile with 480 width and a desktop with 1024 width, you can do something like code below:

```
.advert-img {
    width: 50%;
    height:auto
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

For more info check out this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 0):

Put this media query in your CSS:

```
@media ( max-width: 1024 ) {
  /* Code here works for mobiles and tablets. */
  .advert-img { width: 100%; }
}
```

This will work on all relevant browsers. It will work on Blackberry 4.7.1 and onwards. Check this for Blackberry: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/BB_Browser_content_support_by_version_438586_11.jsp .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve can be done by using Media Queries for CSS3
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/